# Traceroute vs tracert

Tags: windows, fedora, traceroute

I'm having the following issue:

Running `tracert` from Windows 7 returns all the hops to a given server. 
   Running `traceroute` from Fedora 30, using the same connection and the same destination, beyond the gateway IP it returns only * * *.

Could you please explain me why from Windows it is working, but from Fedora is not? What is the difference?

Also, can you advise me how can I make `traceroute` return hops when being ran from Fedora?

Comment: maybe there something like iptables or any other firewall enabled on your Linux client. check your firewall and make sure no rules are defined.

Answer (score 8):

Windows' [`tracert`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/314868/how-to-use-tracert-to-troubleshoot-tcp-ip-problems-in-windows) is using ICMP while incrementing TTL to do probes:

> How to Use the TRACERT Utility
>
> The TRACERT diagnostic utility determines the route to a destination
>   by sending Internet Control Message Protocol (ICMP) echo packets to
>   the destination.

[Fedora](https://apps.fedoraproject.org/packages/traceroute)'s [`traceroute`](http://traceroute.sourceforge.net/), by default, sends UDP probes, as have been previous Unix traceroute implementations doing. The hint UDP is default (beside having double-checked by doing a capture before writing this answer) is from [man](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/traceroute/traceroute.1) which talks first about UDP:

> We don't want the destination host to process the UDP probe packets, so the destination port is set to an unlikely value (you can
>   change it with the -p flag). There is no such a problem for ICMP or
>   TCP tracerouting (for TCP we use half-open technique, which prevents
>   our probes to be seen by applications on the destination host).

Both tools expect to receive [ICMP TIME EXCEEDED](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Control_Message_Protocol#Time_exceeded) as response to build the route.

Along this path, various routers may choose to answer differently (ie: not at all) depending on the probe method used.

If you know that ICMP probes work better for your test, you can do the same on Fedora with:

```
traceroute --icmp destination
```

As ICMP, contrary to UDP, usually requires crafting special packets, the command might require root privileges to run with this option.

Answer (score 1):

This is the difference:

- `tracert`: uses [ICMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Control_Message_Protocol)
- `traceroute`: uses [UDP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Datagram_Protocol)

I have to say that `tracert` lately has become my favourite tool:

[image]